# Modifying AccessDenied SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom, access-denied

I am trying to change the access denied page to add our help desk information and remove "Request access" link. Adding a "p" tag will work but when I try to remove/comment out the line for the asp link for "Request access" it throws me an error. What am I doing wrong? By the way I am editing in notepad directly on the WFE server.

<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%> <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AccessDeniedPage" MasterPageFile="~/_layouts/simple.master"       %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

    " EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/>


    " EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/>


    


    
    


 
 
 
    
        [image]
        " EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/>
    
 
 
    " EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/>

To request access please contact the help desk xxx-xxx-xxxx

```
    <asp:HyperLink id="HLinkLoginAsAnother" Text="<%$SPHtmlEncodedResources:wss,accessDenied_logInAsAnotherOne%>"
        CssClass="ms-descriptiontext" runat="server"/>
    <br/>
    <asp:HyperLink id="HLinkRequestAccess" Text="<%$SPHtmlEncodedResources:wss,accessDenied_requestAccess%>"
        CssClass="ms-descriptiontext" runat="server"/>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

What if you just disable access requests?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You mean comment out?? I am sorry..I cannot see the images you attached above

Comment: No, I mean this. Go you "Site settings" --> "Site permissions" ---> In the ribbon go to "Permissions" tab --> "Access Request Settings" ---> un-check"Allow access request"

Comment: Yes that works for "Request Access". The thing is I want to remove "Sign in as a different User" as well.

Comment: Never change any file in the 14/15/16 hive. Your changes will likely be lost on a patch. Use master page modifications instead.

Comment: Agree with Trevor. Don't modify the OOB files, you can copy Access denied file to a different location and remove markup you don't want. Then check out my answer how to apply the new custom page.

Comment: Thanks @DenisMolodtsov, this is exactly what I needed in my scenario. Gave you an upvote. Cheers.

Comment: This is a very useful suggestion. You can either not allow join requests, or you can customise request access message - for example to say that only people with a legitimate claim to need access will be allowed. "Only those belonging to education department" etc.

Answer (score 2):

For SharePoint 2010, this is the way to create your custom page. Quick and **dirty** way:

- Go to 14 hive folder and create a folder "CustomPages"
- Put your custom .aspx or HTML file there. For example, call it Custom_Access_Denied.aspx
- Run PowerShell command:

  $webApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://yoursite
  $webApp.UpdateMappedPage([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication+SPCustomPage]::AccessDenied,"/_layouts/CustomPages/Custom_Access_Denied.aspx") 
  $webApp.Update()

[More info here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fabdulwahab/2012/10/02/how-to-customize-error-page-page-not-found-and-access-denied-in-sharepoint-2010/)

**Update:**

Proper way would be:

- Create a custom WSP solution
- Add your custom AccessDenied.aspx page to the solution
- Create a Feature and with Feature receivers that apply a custom page and revert it back to the OOB one when feature is deactivated.

**Update 2:**

The reason you cannot remove ASP.NET controls from the ASPX file is that somewhere in in code behind, in OOB SharePoint DLL, these controls are referenced. **I strongly advice against modifying this file**, but if you still want to do it - just wrap the controls you want to hide in a div :

```
<div style='display:none'>
  <asp:HyperLink id="HLinkLoginAsAnother"...
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed steps. I had followed the same steps as above except the powershell command was as below.                                                                                                                 Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage -Identity "AccessDenied" -RelativePath "/_layouts/15/custompages/AccessDeniedNew.aspx" -WebApplication "http:/mywebapplication/"

Comment: Ah... I see what you mean.. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense.  Will try doing that. Thank you so much